# How to pull each element of a line and store it into a variable/array then continue to the next line with Buffer Reader?

Tags: java, csv

I have a multiple row list CSV and I want to pull a line and pull each element from that line in Java. After that I want to go onto the next line. Each row has a different amount of columns so how can I customize the code to that?

I'm at the least looking for some guidance, I can't find anything else like this.

Comment: Search for BufferedReader

Answer (score 0):

If it's reading or writing to/from a csv file, using apache's Commons CSV library could save you the heavy lifting. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html can help. An example (also at the site) could be as:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String lastName = record.get("Last Name");
    String firstName = record.get("First Name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems your file does not have headers for each column. Use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to do this for you - it's 3 times faster than Commons CSV and packed with features.

```
// you have many configuration options here - check the tutorial. By default values are trimmed and blank lines skipped.
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/your/file.csv")));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).